# How to prevent selecting many child div inside a div element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select the `modal-body`

I am using this `$("#modalhapuslampiran > .modal-dialog > .modal-content > .modal body")`

Is there a way to prevent selecting many child `div` inside a child `div` ? I just want to select the `modal-body`

---

```
<div class="modal" id="modalhapuslampiran" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"  style="width: 500px;">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="modal-title">
               <center><h4>PERINGATAN!!</i></h4></center>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer" center>
          <center>
              <button type="button" id="savelampiran_delete" class="btn btn-primary">Ya</button>
              <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Tidak</button>
          </center>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your selector has a space in it instead of a `-`, is it supposed to be `$(".modal > .modal-dialog > .modal-content > .modal-body")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to prevent selecting many child div inside a child div
>   ? i just want to select `modal-body`

Then use that selector alone like this:

```
$(".modal-body")
```

or use [**`find()`**](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(".modal").find(".modal-body")
```

or to be even more unique use the modal ID like this

```
$("#modalhapuslampiran").find(".modal-body")
```

Comment: i am sorry i mean ijust want to select the specific div

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this is to use jQuerys .find() method, this savs you chaining your elements in the selector. so you should be able to do the following and achieve the same result:

```
$(".modal").find("modal-body")
```